# Yii 2 Editable, how to use editable inside form?

Tags: yii2

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin();
..
echo Editable::widget([ //this break outter form, because this generate another form
    'name'=>'person_name', 
    'asPopover' => true,
    'value' => 'Kartik Visweswaran',
    'header' => 'Name',
    'size'=>'md',
    'options' => ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Enter person name...']
]);
ActiveForm::end();
```

So, I tried,

```
echo Form::widget([
    'model'=>$model,
    'form'=>$form,
    'columns'=>1,
    'attributes'=>[
        'title'=>[
            'label'=>false,
            'type' => Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
            'widgetClass' => Editable::className(),
            'options' => [
                'asPopover' => true,
            ]
        ],
    ]
]);
```

but, it shows input box all the time, not editable text.

how can I use editable widget inside form? without breaking outter form?

Comment: see demo at : http://demos.krajee.com/editable

Comment: @InsaneSkulll Could you show me a little more specific please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'person_name')->Editable::widget([
   'name'=>'person_name',
   'asPopover' => true,
   'value' => 'value',
   'header' => 'Name',
   'size'=>'md',
   'options' => ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Enter person name...']
  ]);
?>
```

**Note :** Not tested yet.

Comment: Thank you for your help,  but still it generates another form and outter form is not working. I tried, ```<?= $form->field($model, 'title')->widget(Editable::classname(), [
   'name'=>'title',
   'asPopover' => false,
   'value' => 'value',
   'header' => 'Name',
   'size'=>'md',
   'options' => ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Enter person name...']
  ]);
?>```

Comment: use this `$form = ActiveForm::begin();` or so whole `_form.php`